# Implement Linked List with No Node Class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I am implementing a Linked list in Python. Almost all implementations use a `Node` class separately from the actual LinkedList class. I am trying to do it within a single class.

So what I would like is to be able to add in 3 elements, and then print them out. My guess is that this would require some form of recursion. Here, I add two elements (1.0 and -1.0), and then print the list.

```
ll = LinkedList(1.0)
ll.insert_front(-1.0)
print(ll._linkedlist)

#output
[-1.0, [1.0, None]]
```

This looks good. Notice the last element contains the second element (1.0) and the pointer which points to `None` - shown here as `[1.0, None]`

However, this falls apart whenever I try to add a third element.

```
ll.insert_front(3.0)
[3.0, [-1.0, None]]
```

What I would like is the following output:

```
[3.0, [-1.0, [1.0, None]]]
```

Any ideas how to do this? My current implementation is below.

```
class LinkedList(object):
        """A data structure implemented in Python.  
        """
        def __init__(self, head):
            """Initialize List."""
            self.head = head
            self.size = 1
            self.next = None
            self._linkedlist = [self.head, self.next]
            empty_ll = None

        def insert_front(self, element):
            self.next = self.head
            self.head = element
            self.size += 1
            self._linkedlist[0] = self.head
            self._linkedlist[1] = [self.next, empty_ll]

        #print out the head of the linked list
        def __repr__(self): 
           return 'LinkedList(%s)' % (self.head)
```

Comment: The reason why it don't work is because each time you add a element you always MODIFY the element 0 and 1 from __self._linkedlist__. Try inserting it in the first pos, without changing the pos 0 and 1 from the list.